# "curl" does not work in script

Tags: bash, curl

I wrote curl which returns only http status code :

```
curl --write-out %{http_code} \n
     --silent \
     --output /dev/null \ 
      $URL
```

It works fine if I execute this from console. But after I have puted it into script, like this:

```
HTTP_STATUS=$(curl --write-out %{http_code} \n
            --silent \
            --output /dev/null \ 
            $URL)
```

And try to echo $HTTP_STATUS, result is 200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

How can I fix it?

Comment: `echo "$HTTP_STATUS"` .. or probably use lowercase variable `echo "$http_status"`

Comment: Also mind quoting the `$URL` ? Well, do use lowercase here too. :-)

Comment: It works for me. Consider debugging your script by putting `#!/bin/bash -vx`in the first line, and show the script as an [MCVE] in your question. Be aware of your [`PATH` variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable))

Comment: When you're assigning to a variable you don't need to end with `\n`.

Comment: Are you sure the first command works? Shouldn't `%{http_code}` and `\n` be in the same argument, or quoted if you want a space before the newline?

Comment: And you need to quote `\n` so that `curl` will see the backslash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I wrote curl which returns **`only`** http status code

There are couple of issues with your script.

- Your use of UPPERCASE variables might override shell environment variables.
- The `--write-out` argument of the curl can ideally be within double quotes.

---

```
status=$(curl --write-out "%{http_code}" --silent --output /dev/null "$url")
echo "$status" # Would give you just the status
```

<sup>**Note:** As pointed out in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48260566/curl-does-not-work-in-script/48260982?noredirect=1#comment83504737_48260566) comment you don't need the newline too since you're assigning the value to a variable.</sup>

Comment: Commands can't tell whether the arguments are in quotes or not, the quotes are processed by the shell. And why would it work in the first case but not the second?

Comment: @Barmar I don't think it works in the first case too. If it does, it is  not the way op wanted it.

Comment: Yeah, I wonder about having two arguments after `--write-out`.

Comment: @Barmar Ahh! I now see the inspiration in writing the first part of comment #1. He needs a newline, though  if he is not doing an assignment, ie if he is just running the command and then double quotes comes into play.